# Express.js server side error message notworking

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

this is my server side POST code .before my task saving database im find same data in the database using my unique value as `service` but when i run this code console says `ReferenceError: service is not defined`

what is wrong here?can some one poine me.please

```
app.post('/collections/:collectionName', function(req, res, next) {
        req.collection.findOne({service: service}, function(e, result){
           if(result){
              res.send{error: "REQUEST ALREADY EXISTS"};
           }
           else{
              req.collection.insert(req.body, {}, function(e, results){
                 if (e) return next(e)
                    res.send(results)
              });
           }
        });
})
```

**update----**

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        var service_ = service.value;
        var amount_ = amount.value;
        var name_ = name.value;
        var phone_ = phone.value;
        var reminder_ = reminder.value;

        if (start_pick < end_pick) {
            var jsondata = [{
                start_time : new Date(start_pick),
                end_time : new Date(end_pick),
                service : service_,
                amount : amount_,
                client_phone : phone_,
                client_name : name_,
                reminder : reminder_
            }];

            var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
            xhr.setTimeout(10000);

            xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/collections/appoinments");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsondata));
            xhr.onerror = function() {

                Titanium.API.info("Error in connecting to server !!");
                alert("Error on connecting to server, Please try again");
            };
             xhr.onload = function() {

            windowPayment.close();

    }
```

Comment: Well, what's `service`?

Comment: @dave-newton `service` is value i get from user input

Comment: Where does that happen?

Comment: The JSON request data sent from the POST should be in `req.body`, so the variable you are looking for is `req.body.service`.

Comment: @jcoc611 then error is gone thanks. :) but still same data inserting to database.?

Comment: @jcoc611 in here must i user `({service: req.body.service}, function(e, result){`  or `({req.body.service: req.body.service}, function(e, result){`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sent by the POST request will be accessible through `req.body`, so the variable you are looking for is `req.body.service`. Also, assuming the function `req.collection.findOne` uses the property `service` of the first argument, you should keep the code as following:

```
 req.collection.findOne({service: req.body.service}, function(e, result){
     //...
 });
```

Given that an object `{req.body.service: ...}` is invalid.